# How to check if Win 7 disk is Ultimate or Home Premium or Professional version?

Tags: windows-7

A friend of mine found an old Windows7 disk but is unable to determine the point mentioned in the title. I have checked the `autorun.ini` file, the contents of which is this:

```
[AutoRun.Amd64]
open=setup.exe
icon=setup.exe,0

[AutoRun]
open=sources\sperr32.exe x64
icon=sources\sperr32.exe,0
```

How can I determine what version this Windows disk is?

Comment: Also see: [Windows 7 Home Premium and Professional same media?](http://superuser.com/questions/53398/windows-7-home-premium-and-professional-same-media?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 7 disks contain all the editions, the specific one is chosen during installation. If you enter a product key during installation, you will get the edition that the key is for. If you do not enter a product key, you will be presented with a list of all editions. Beware though, if you choose one, you must obtain a valid product key for *that edition* within 30 days to activate it.

A different question is if the disc is for x86 or x64 systems. Judging by the autorun.ini file, it is an x64 disc.

Comment: It seems they have both the kinds of ISO's: some will have all the versions, others won't- they will be specific. Anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to create a Virtual Machine, and try installing Windows. In some point you will be asked for the key. See if it accepts Ultimate key. If it does, it is probably an Ultimate or Ultimate/Professional version. If it fails, try a Home Premium key. You can use Oracle's Virtualbox, VMWare's Player or whatever virtual machine application you want. If it is an 64-bit DVD you will need a 64-bit host system to install it. You cannot use a 32-bit host for a 64-bit guest.

Another way is to open in Notepad some specific files in the root folder of the DVD and check some specific details, but I don't remember now, so I cannot help you there. I would go for the first method. Once you find out, use a permanent marker to write it on the disk so you remember next time.

Comment: Isn't that trial-and-error method? Can't we get a straight-forward way to do this?